# Java Generics Compare Number with Byte

Tags: java, generics

Why can't `Byte` and `Number/Integer` be compared? I have attached my source code. See the comments. Also why I have to cast 88 into byte, isn't it done automatically with auto-boxing and auto-unboxing?

```
package com.practice;

public class Generics<T extends Number>
{
    T ob;

public Generics(T i)
{
    ob = i;
}

T getObj()
{
    return ob;
}

boolean compare(Generics<?> o)
{

    if (this.ob == o.ob)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Generics<Number> num = new Generics<>(88);

    // Generics<Byte> Byte = new Generics<>(88); //why this does not
    // compile?

    Generics<Byte> Byte = new Generics<>((byte) 88);

    Generics<Integer> integer = new Generics<>(88);

    System.out.println(num.compare(integer)); // this is true!!
    System.out.println(num.compare(Byte)); // why False?
    System.out.println(integer.compare(Byte)); // Why false?

}

}
```

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to achieve, but the fact of the matter is that `Number` does not implement `Comparable`; so this is expected

Comment: This isnt the normal compareTo() function.I have created my own.My question is stated in the comments at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I have to cast 88 into byte, isn't it done automatically with auto-boxing and auto-unboxing?

By default, a numeric literal (like `88`) is an `int`. The auto-boxing does happen but the compiler boxes it into an `Integer` and not a `Byte` because, as I just told, it's an `int`.

```
Generics<Number> num = new Generics<>(88);
Generics<Integer> integer = new Generics<>(88);
```

Since, an `Integer` *IS-A* `Number` both of the above work just fine.

```
Generics<Byte> Byte = new Generics<>(88); // why this does not compile?
```

Now, in case of `Generics<Byte>`, the *constructor* becomes `Generics(Byte i)`, which fails because an `Integer` cannot be assigned to a `Byte` as there's no inheritance between them. They both extend `Number` and are sibling classes.

```
Generics<Byte> Byte = new Generics<>((byte) 88);
```

So, to pass in a `Byte` and satisfy the compiler, the `(byte)` cast is required. Now the auto-boxing happens again but from a `byte` to `Byte` this time.

---

Regarding equality, your `compare()` method implementation is flawed because it only compares references `this.ob == o.ob` and not their values.

```
System.out.println(num.compare(integer)); // this is true!!
System.out.println(num.compare(Byte)); // why False?
System.out.println(integer.compare(Byte)); // Why false?
```

This however worked for integer comparison `num.compare(integer)` because you chose a small value `88` which falls in the range of values (-128 to +127) cached and shared by the JVM among *auto-boxed* `Integer` instances. If you run your program again with a larger value like `888`, it will print `false` for the same comparison.

So, to fix your `compare()` method, you'll need to sort of unbox their numeric values.

```
return (this.ob.floatValue() == o.ob.floatValue());
```

*PS: The equals() method wouldn't help here. Check the source code to know why :)*

Comment: Wow! Detailed explaination.Thanks,especially clearing the compare() query.